# how to convert multiple json object into one object using jq?

Tags: jq

Input:

```
{
  "ip": {
    "ip_ip_dst": "4.2.2.2",
    "ip_ip_src": "192.168.2.208"
  },
  "dns": {
    "text_dns_qry_class": "0x00000001",
    "text_dns_a": "104.199.136.182",
    "text_dns_qry_name_len": "15",
    "text_dns_qry_name": "vehere.odoo.com",
    "text_dns_resp_type": "1",
    "text_dns_qry_type": "1"
  },
  "frame": {
    "frame_frame_len": "79",
    "frame_frame_time": "Aug 9, 2017 13:21:29.987979869 IST"
  }
}
```

Output should be:

```
{
    "ip_ip_dst": "4.2.2.2",
    "ip_ip_src": "192.168.2.208"
    "text_dns_qry_class": "0x00000001",
    "text_dns_a": "104.199.136.182",
    "text_dns_qry_name_len": "15",
    "text_dns_qry_name": "vehere.odoo.com",
    "text_dns_resp_type": "1",
    "text_dns_qry_type": "1"
    "frame_frame_len": "79",
    "frame_frame_time": "Aug 9, 2017 13:21:29.987979869 IST"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `add` function:

```
jq 'add' file.json
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[.[]] | add
```

should do the trick.